# SQL command to find items without joined rows

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables with tables structure like that:

```
| Items |
---------
|  Id   |
---------

|Orders |
---------
|  Id   |
|Item_id|
|Status |
---------

|Reserves |
---------
|  Id   |
|Item_id|
|Status |
---------

|Holdings |
---------
|  Id   |
|Item_id|
|Status |
---------

|Deliveries |
---------
|  Id   |
|Item_id|
|Status |
---------
```

Every table can have millions of rows. And I'm trying to get all Items that are not present in all other tables. I tried to do this and then in my program filter IDs that are not received in select:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Items
JOIN Orders ON Orders.Item_id = Items.Id
JOIN Reserves ON Reserves.Item_id = Items.Id
JOIN Holdings ON Holdings.Item_id = Items.Id
JOIN Deliveries ON Reserves.Item_id = Items.Id
GROUP BY Items.ID
```

But there are two issues: 1) It's ultra-slow on million-rows DB 2) It requires additional code to filter them.

Is there a better way to get all Items without rows linked to them in other tables?
Basically all items without orders, reserves, holdings, and deliveries.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How many values from `Items` is not present in each separate other table (approximately, of course)? Is `Item_id` (and `id` in `Items`) indexed in each table?

Comment: They are indexed. About 200 items are not present. Thanks.

Comment: *About 200 items are not present.* ~200 Orders.Item_id not present in Items.Id, and ~200 Reserves.Item_id not present in Items.Id, and so on ... ?

Comment: Or ~X0000 Orders.Item_id not present in Items.Id, and ~Y0000 Reserves.Item_id not present in Items.Id, and so on ... and totally ~ 200 is present in none table?

Comment: Yes, I need all that is not present in any of the tables, so Items.Id without corresponding rows in any of the 5 tables.

Comment: If so then I don't see the answer to my question: How many values from Items table is not present **in each separate other table** (approximately, of course)? For example, how many values Items.Id is approx. absent in Orders.Item_id?

Comment: ~200 in total for all tables, and it's about 500 absent for each table, and it will result in 200 absent items at the intersection of all tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have an index on `(item_id)` for each of the tables `orders`, `reserves`, `holdings` and `deliveries` and an index on `items (id)`.

Then try to either use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM items i
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM orders o
                                WHERE o.item_id = i.id)
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM reserves r
                                    WHERE r.item_id = i.id)
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM holdings h
                                    WHERE h.item_id = i.id)
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM deliveries
                                    WHERE d.item_id = i.id);
```

Or try a left join:

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM items i
            LEFT JOIN orders o
                      ON o.item_id = i.id
            LEFT JOIN reserves r
                      ON r.item_id = i.id
            LEFT JOIN holdings h
                      ON h.item_id = i.id
            LEFT JOIN deliveries d
                      ON d.item_id = i.id
       WHERE o.item_id IS NULL
             AND r.item_id IS NULL
             AND h.item_id IS NULL
             AND d.item_id IS NULL;
```

When in doubt, check the plan to see what is better.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that given the size of the dataset, any approach is likely to be relatively slow.

You could `UNION` the other tables and `SELECT` from `Items` where the `ID` isn't present in them:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  Items
  WHERE (ID NOT IN (
                   SELECT  Item_id
                     FROM  Orders
                   UNION
                   SELECT  Item_id
                     FROM  Reserves 
                   UNION
                   SELECT  Item_id
                     FROM  Holdings 
                   UNION
                   SELECT  Item_id
                     FROM  Deliveries 
                   )
        )
```

This would get all of the *unique* `Item_id` from the four tables and then return rows from `Items` where the `ID` is *not* present.  It's likely to be fairly slow though given the volume of data.

Potentially you could use `UNION ALL` instead, which would not bother filtering out duplicates, potentially speeding up the union and not affecting the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

> How many values from Items is not present in each separate other table (approximately, of course)? Is Item_id (and id in Items) indexed in each table? – Akina
>
> They are indexed. About 200 items are not present. Thanks. – John John

Do you need in

```
SELECT Items.Id
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.Item_id = Items.Id
WHERE Orders.Item_id IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT Items.Id
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Reserves ON Reserves.Item_id = Items.Id
WHERE Reserves.Item_id IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT Items.Id
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Holdings ON Holdings.Item_id = Items.Id
WHERE Holdings.Item_id IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT Items.Id
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Deliveries ON Deliveries.Item_id = Items.Id
WHERE Deliveries.Item_id IS NULL
```

? This returns `Items.Id` which cannot be found in at least of one another table.

---

> How many values from Items is not present in each separate other table (approximately, of course)? – Akina

> ~200 in total for all tables, and it's about 500 absent for each table, and it will result in 200 absent items at the intersection of all tables. – John John

If you need the values which are present in none other table then you must JOIN these subqueries, not UNION them:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM 

( SELECT Items.Id
  FROM Items
  LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.Item_id = Items.Id
  WHERE Orders.Item_id IS NULL ) t1

NATURAL JOIN

( SELECT Items.Id
  FROM Items
  LEFT JOIN Reserves ON Reserves.Item_id = Items.Id
  WHERE Reserves.Item_id IS NULL ) t2

NATURAL JOIN

( SELECT Items.Id
  FROM Items
  LEFT JOIN Holdings ON Holdings.Item_id = Items.Id
  WHERE Holdings.Item_id IS NULL ) t3

NATURAL JOIN

( SELECT Items.Id
  FROM Items
  LEFT JOIN Deliveries ON Deliveries.Item_id = Items.Id
  WHERE Deliveries.Item_id IS NULL ) t4
```